# Use "nor" or use "or"?

Tags: conjunctions

Jerry is *neither* rich *nor* famous. I know this is correct. 
Is this correct? Jerry *isn't* rich *nor* famous. It doesn't sound natural to me, but I can't find a reason why it wouldn't be right.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think the OP is asking — "Can you use 'nor' after 'not'?" rather than "Should I use 'nor' after 'neither'?". Would be good to clarify alright though.

Comment: Better: *Jimmy isn't (either) rich or famous*. Although *either* may be omitted, it's understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

If you didn't omit the verb/subject in the second half of the sentence, you would reverse them, and say:

> Jerry isn't rich, nor is he famous

But keeping the omission is also fine, for example:

> Still Peter was **not rich nor famous**, he was neither a ruler of the synagogue, nor an eminent scribe
>
> — [The Complete Works of C. H. Spurgeon, Volume 23: Sermons 1331-1390](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xssvCgAAQBAJ)

That said, it definitely does sound more formal (and a little old-fashioned perhaps), versus using 'or'.

Comment: Older writers, even through the nineteenth century, were more liberal about usage of _nor_ than today's. Ralph Waldo Emerson, for example,  wrote, "All great men have written proudly nor cared to explain" (link too long to include, but it comes up on a Google search); modern grammar requires _and not_ or _but not_ instead of _nor_.